# jQuery event.data is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

i have the next code for extract the id value from jQuery, but not work.

jQuery:

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#modificarMantenimiento').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

                $.ajax({url: "{{ path("agc_modificar_mantenimiento") }}?idmantenimiento="+$(event).data('idmantenimiento'), success: function(result){
                    $("#modal-content").html(result);
                }});
            })
        })
</script>
```

HTML:

```
{% for m in mantenimiento %}
                          <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-1">{% if m.esvigente == 1 %} <span style="color:#759E1A"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>{% else %} <span style="color:#ff0000"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span> {% endif %}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3" data-toggle="modal" data-idmantenimiento="{{m.idequipoactividadmantenimiento}}" data-target="#modificarMantenimiento"><a style="cursor:pointer">{{m.idempresamantenimiento}}</a></td>
                            <td class="col-md-1">{{m.mfechainicio | date("Y-m-d")}}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-1">{{m.fechafin | date("Y-m-d")}}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-2">{{m.idtipomantenimiento}}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">{% if m.observaciones is not empty %}{{m.observaciones |capitalize}}{% else %}<p class="text-muted">--</p>{% endif %}</td>
                          </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

When i clicked the td with data-target, i get that `$(event).data('idmantenimiento')` is undefined.

Comment: Hi! I have changed $(event).data('idmantenimiento') for $(this).data('idmantenimiento'), but continues undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(event.relatedTarget).data('idmantenimiento')
```

The `relatedTarget` should by the item that you clicked to start the modal

[More information](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)